# Typescript: 'jasmine' methods are not recognized properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Jasmin methods (i.e. createSpyOjb) are not recognized though I've added a definition file.

[image: jasmin with typescript]

Any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the below code working perfectly with the latest definitions from [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jasmine.d.ts" />

var fs = jasmine.createSpyObj('fs', ['readfile']);
var callback = jasmine.createSpy('callback');

var rek = require('rekuire');
var proxykuire = rek('proxykuire').proxykuire;
var getMenuDataCommand = rek('GetMenuDataCommand');

describe('GetMenuDataCommand', function () {
    var getMenuDataCommand;
    var fs;
    var callback;

    beforeEach(function () {
        fs = jasmine.createSpyObj('fs', ['readFile']);
        callback = jasmine.createSpy('callback');

        var getMenuDataCommand = proxykuire('GetMenuDataCommand', { fs: fs });
        getMenuDataCommand = new getMenuDataCommand();
    });
});
```

The only difference (unless I typed something in wrong) is that my references are closer to my TypeScript file. I get full intelliSense and no errors.

**WebStorm**

I just tested in WebStorm and it doesn't seem to support TypeScript 0.9, which will be a stumbling block if you use WebStorm. (It didn't recognise the `boolean` type and hasn't got the `export = internal;` support).

You could use older versions of the definitions (from before they were updated to TypeScript 0.9) to get you going for now and then update when WebStorm gets 0.9 language support.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know you were using WebStorm - additional section added.

Answer (score 0):

For WebStorm, refer to this documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html, section `Downloading and installing a JavaScript-related library from WebStorm`

More information about Typescript support:
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/typescript-support.html

**TL;DR;** WebStorm doesn't seem to understand <reference> yet. Configure JavaScript libraries on WebStorm settings.